# Rename several files by some pattern python

Tags: python, filenames, rename

I would like to build a python script to do the following

change all occurrences of "bla" to "abd" in the file names.
For instance:

> 123_bla.dd -> 123_abd.dd
>   *bla*.dd -> _abd.dd

How can I do that?

I tried:

```
for fn in os.listdir("."):
    print fn  # test
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(fn, '*bla*'):
        fn = fn.replace(fn, "abd")
        print fn
```

Comment: It's worth noting there is already a widely available `rename` perl script that does exactly this -- that's assuming you just want to use it anyway, nothing wrong with building one.

Comment: You're just changing the string containing the files' names, not the actual filenames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `replace` method correctly: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace

You have to do `fn.replace('bla', 'abd')`. And then of course do the actual renaming https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename

Answer (score 0):

You're just changing the string containing the files' names, not the actual filenames. Try using [os.rename()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename)

```
for fn in os.listdir("."):
    print fn  # test
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(fn, "bla):
        fixed = fn.replace("bla", "abd")
        os.rename(fn, fixed)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks like it just changes all file names to "abd" instead of only replacing the "bla"

Comment: Exactly, because that's what `fn.replace(fn, 'abd')` does. See also my answer.

Comment: Ah, that's right, doesn't work with how you change the names. +1 for Jasper's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You are just getting the names of the files in strings and then renaming them, you need to rename the files using the `os.rename()` method.